# Extract value from json string

Tags: objective-c, json, api

I am trying to learn how to use API's with Objective-C. I am using the data from here: https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker and I only want the 'last' value. I have tried extracting the value like this:

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker"];
NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError * error;

NSMutableDictionary  * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
NSArray *keys = [json allKeys];
NSString *jsonStr = [json objectForKey:keys[0]];

NSArray *c1 = [jsonStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"last = \""];
NSArray *c2 = [[c1 objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\";"];
NSString *result = [c2 objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

However, this gives me the following errors:

```
2014-03-02 15:03:24.915 Litecoin Ticker[5727:303] -[__NSDictionaryM componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000240690
2014-03-02 15:03:24.915 Litecoin Ticker[5727:303] -[__NSDictionaryM componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000240690
```

I'm not entirely sure this is only way to extract values from API's, but i can't seem to find out how to do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It takes 5-10 minutes and knowing it makes everything easier to understand.

Comment: And there is no need to use `componentsSeparatedByString`.  Just reference the NSDictionarys using `objectForKey` (or the new form using `[]`).  `NSNumber* last = json[@"ticker"][@"last"];`

Comment: (And, especially when taking data off the web, always check the value back from NSJSONSerialization and, if nil, at least NSLog the `error` value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *jsonStr = [json objectForKey:keys[0]];
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// nope, it's a NSDictionary...
```

...and it has already been parsed!

And if you `NSLog` it you will see it's content. Here's how you access the `last` field after you have the JSON parsed by `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
NSNumber *last = json[@"ticker"][@"last"];
```

And that's it.

---

As a side note

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

is awful, since it's synchronous! Consider using an asynchronous approach (the nuclear - and probably best - option is to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)). Here's a complete `AFNetworking` example:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
    NSNumber *last = JSON[@"ticker"][@"last"];
    NSLog(@"last value: %@", last);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I was overcomplicating it that much! What does the AFNetworking part do?

Comment: It's a networking framework. It basically wraps the Objective-C networking API into a nicer block-based one.

Comment: @user2397282 w.r.t. your specific case it makes the call asynchronous, so that it doesn't block the thread you're performing it on (if it's the main thread you're going to block the UI, until the request is performed!)

Comment: Note that the return value for `last` will be an NSNumber, not an NSString.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I have tried using your asynchronous approach, but it gives me an error when I run, basically saying that the data in the link is in the wrong format: text/html, not json?

Comment: @user239782 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794712/afnetworking-2-response-error-content-type-text-html-and-not-json